# Move back all objects to original position in excel VBA Userforms

Tags: excel, vba, userform

**Scenario**

I have an excel VBA userform whereby it has many combobox, text box, labels, checkbox and buttons all around. When I click some button these object will change its position to a new position.

**What I need**

I need to move back all these to the original position when a button is clicked without using the positioning technique I used earlier. Is there any method whereby I can move all objects back to original position with some single command?

**What I tried**

I tried `userform_initialize` but its not working

Comment: Can't you just record the position of all objects in each object's .tag property after on userform_initialize, and then use that to reset things back to the original position when required?

Comment: I think it is somewhat similar like getting all the left and top position of objects at the beginning and then again use back all these positions to return those to original place. But what I need to know is, if there is any straightforward method? something like reset userform directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jeffrey Weir pointed out; Put the original positions in the Tag property

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        ctrl.Tag = ctrl.Top & "|" & ctrl.Left
    Next
End Sub
```

and to go back to the original positions:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'button to go back, adjust name to your button
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        ctrl.Top = Split(ctrl.Tag, "|")(0)
        ctrl.Left = Split(ctrl.Tag, "|")(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This works like a charm. I marked this as the answer. But do you mind explain a bit about how this tag thing works? I never used this tag property so far. so I don't quite understand how this code works.

Comment: a Tag property can be used as a storage for whatever you additional want to store, in this case the origin position of your control. So here the position is stored as "Top|Left", when splitting this Text with the "|"-pipe as a delimiter, you get an array with the Top (0) and Left (1).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Now I understood clearly

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot do this easily. The only built-in Excel method which "resets" the last action is `Application.Undo`. From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-undo-method-excel):

> This method undoes only the last action taken by the user before
>   running the macro, and it must be the first line in the macro. It
>   cannot be used to undo Visual Basic commands.

Comment: Sadly, `Application.Undo` is not applicable for my scenario :(

Comment: Then I think I have to do the tedious way by finding original positions of all objects and then move all objects based on those original positions :(

Comment: Yes, that was kinda my point with my answer, since the quote says "It cannot be used to undo Visual Basic commands." Sorry mate, no easy solution here except for the ugly one which involves unloading the userform and then displaying it again.

Comment: I have only one userform. So I can't do the unloading and reloading. Instead I have to reposition all the objects by adjusting the top and left properties.

Comment: You could achieve this with a small recursive procedure which loads/unloads the userform. This might be considerably easier than repositioning the elements, but it would still create a somewhat weird user experience since the userform would "blink" for a second or so while it unloads and then reinitialises.

Comment: But with one userform, how should I load and unload it?

Comment: With a **recursive** procedure, as I stated, but for several reasons, I get the feeling that you might be better off by simply writing a procedure which repositions the elements "manually". Anyway, you might consider accepting the answer. Thx.

Comment: Thank you @Miqi180 for helping out. Eventually I got a very clean working code by using tag property stated above which is able to move all the objects promptly to original position